# Titanium Appcelerator: TableView sliding up inside a NavigationWindow upon second open

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, modal-window

I'm having trouble getting my TableView to stay put. As the code below shows, the TableView resides inside the second window, which itself resides inside a NavigationWindow
My question is: Is it possible for a NavigationWindow to be modal, and if so, why is the TableView sliding up the second time it's opened? Am I missing something?

Edit: It's not just specific to tableviews, this is happening for any view added to the window.

I'm using 3.2.3.GA

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', title: 'first window' });
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({ title: 'click me', left: 0, right: 0 });
var button2 = Ti.UI.createButton({ title: 'click me', left: 0, right: 0 });
var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', leftNavButton: button2 });
var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({ top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 });
var navigationWindow = Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({ window : win2, modal: true});

var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ title: 'test' });

tableView.setData([row]);

win2.add(tableView);
win.add(button);

win.open();

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    navigationWindow.open();
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    navigationWindow.close();
});
```

[image: first open]
[image: second open]

Answer (score 0):

you should change some code: This is a example how to add a modal Window with a NavigationController and a tableView inside.

```
// create modal window

    ModalWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title : 'This is my Window'
    });

// Add TableView and Add it to your Window

    var TableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({ top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 });
    ModalWindow.add(TableView);

//  Add a NavigationControllerWindow, and add your Modal Window to it

   var NavWindow = Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
        modal : true,
        window : ModalWindow
    });

// Open it modal    

    button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        NavWindow.open({
            modalStyle : Ti.UI.iPhone.MODAL_PRESENTATION_PAGESHEET
        });
     });
```

Comment: Hi derdida, as far as I can tell the only difference between our code is the 'Ti.UI.iPhone.MODAL_PRESENTATION_PAGESHEET' constant. After adding this, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Can u provide a screenshot?

Comment: Added two screenshots, the first shows the first time the modal is opened (this is what I'm going for). The second time the modal is opened (the second screenshot) the tableview slides up.

Comment: That sounds strange. Maybe the contentInsets is a problem. You are developing for iOS7+? Try  tableView.setContentInsets({top:0},{animated:false});

Comment: Right it's iOS7. This unfortunately didn't work either. Perhaps I've found a bug then. I've also asked on the appcelerator forums and haven't had any replies. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Maybe try a simple ListView instead of a TableView.